# Can't follow AutoMapper's documentation - where is CreateMapper?

Tags: automapper, automapper-4

I've encountered a problem while upgrading from AutoMapper's static API.

I'm following the example on [this page](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Migrating-from-static-API), which states that

> Typical usage from 4.1 and before was:
>
> ```
> Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
>      cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
>      cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>(); });
>
> var dest = Mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(new Source());
> ```
>
> In 4.2 and later, this would look like:
>
> ```
> var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
>      cfg.AddProfile<AppProfile>();
>      cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
> });
>
> var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
> var dest = mapper.Map<Source, Dest>(new Source());
> ```

However, while using v4.2.1 via NuGet I can't see this 'CreateMapper' method.

What am I supposed to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised what was causing my problem.

In order to use the `MapperConfiguration` application-wide I was storing it as a static property:

```
public static IMapperConfiguration { get; private set; }

public static void Init()
{
    MapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(...);
    ...
    MapperConfiguration.    // CreateMapper() not available
}
```

The problem here is that the `CreateMapper` method is only available on the `MapperConfiguration` **class**, not the `IMapperConfiguration` **interface**.